# JavaScript - How to draw black outline (or stroke) for a red line - leaflet mapbox

Tags: javascript, leaflet, line, draw, mapbox

I try to figure out how to draw linestring with `fillcolor: red` and `outline: black`. Like the following image:

[image]

```
style = {
        fillColor: 'rgb(255,0,0)',
        outline: 'rgb(0,0,0)'
        weight: 10
    };
```

It does not work, maybe I need to use strokeStyle?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#path - `color` sets the stroke color.

Comment: Thank you @Caramiriel,
That means I need to use like this
['code']style = {
        fillColor: 'rgb(255,0,0)',// for path
        color:  'rgb(0,0,0)', // for stroke (line borders - black)
        //outline: 'rgb(0,0,0)', // do not use "outline" parameter
        weight: 10
    };

Comment: @Caramiriel, it does not work for me. According to the manual - it is impossible, if you think it is possible, please provide working example for this case. Thanks

Comment: @Caramiriel, it does not work for me. I will explain: I need to draw a road on a map - Polyline. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polyline
According to the manual - it is impossible, if you think it is possible, please provide working example for this case. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lines do not, and cannot have a fill colour.

What you really want is to draw *two* line symbols per line geometry, while making sure the black line is drawn *first* (i.e. *behind*) the red one.

In Leaflet, create *two* map panes, make sure their z-indexes are right (read the tutorial!), add layers as appropriate, reusing the line geometry but changing the symbol appearance.

Answer (score 0):

@mik1971
Look at this example. My situation is similar, but it is not efficient for other possible analyzes:

```
var geojson = new L.geoJson(data, {                            
            style: function (feature) {                                                                      
            return {color: 'black', opacity: 1, weight: 3};
        }
        }).addTo(map);
    
        var geojson = new L.geoJson(data, {                        
            style: function (feature) {                                 
                var c;                                                
                switch (feature.properties.dpv_cal) {
                    case 'Pavimentada':
                        c = '#ff0127';                                  
                        break;
                    case 'Mejorada':
                        c = '#db6adb';
                        break;
                    case 'Natural':
                        c = '#ffffff';
                        break;
                    default:
                        c = 'grey';
                        break;
                }
            return {color: c, opacity: 1, weight: 2};
            }
        }).addTo(map);
    }
});
```

I have declared two times my geojson and it works.